# How to use author-year reference style in Springer template in Latex

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I want to get Springer Author-Year refernce style from `*.bib` file in LaTeX as follows,

> Hamburger, C.: Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of partial differential equations. Ann. Mat. Pura Appl. 169, 321–354 (1995)

I used the following Springer Template code as

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3} 

\smartqed 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{Test Title}
\author{First Author \and Second Author }

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Test abstract
\end{abstract}

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{testbib}  

\end{document}
```

But I couldn't get any reference list in my `.pdf` file after run the .tex file. I am using PDFLaTeX in Kile Tex editor to run the `.tex` file. I am very beginner for bib file concept.  So guide me to get the above reference style in my document. Also guide me how to cite the reference in thew document. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to `\cite{key}` the references in your document (you did not show in your mwe) and to run the usual chain `pdflatex mwe.tex`, **`bibtex mwe`**, `pdflatex mwe.tex`, `pdflatex mwe.tex`.

Comment: Yes .. As per your guidelines I got the output.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in comments.